# c# get repository by entity type

Tags: c#, generics

I design some application with using Repository pattern. I have a generic repository:

```
public interface IGenericRepository<T> where T : class { // ... }

public class GenericRepository <T> : IGenericRepository<T> where T : class {// ... }
```

For example, I have two entities: Order and OrderLine.
For entity "Order" I need only generic repository methods, so it's OK.
But for entity "OrderLine" I need some generic repository methods and some addtitional. So, I create a custom repository, which extends generic:

```
    public interface IOrderLinesRepository : IGenericRepository<OrderLine> {...}
    public class OrderLinesRepository : GenericRepository<OrderLine>, IOrderLinesRepository 
    {
      //... this is my additional methods here
    }
```

But now I want to create method, which will return a repository by entity type.
If entity has a custom repository - it should be retuned. If not, method must return GenericRepository. Here is my attempt to create this.

```
public sealed class RepositoryFactory
{

    // Here is custom repository types
    private IDictionary<Type, Func<DbContext, object>> GetCustomFactories()
    {
        return new Dictionary<Type, Func<DbContext, object>>
        {
            { typeof(OrderLine), dbContext => 
                  new OrderLinesRepository(dbContext) },
        };
    }

    // Custom repository types
    private IDictionary<Type, Type> GetRepositoryTypes()
    {
        return new Dictionary<Type, Type>
        {
            { typeof(OrderLine), typeof(IOrderLinesRepository) }
        };
    }

    private Func<GoodWillDbContext, object> GetDefaultFactory<T>() 
       where T : class
    {
        return dbContext => new GenericRepository<T>(dbContext);
    }

    private Func<DbContext, object> GetFactory<T>() where T : class
    {
        Func<DbContext, object> factory;
        var factories = GetCustomFactories();
        factories.TryGetValue(typeof(T), out factory);
        return factory ?? (factory = GetDefaultFactory<T>());
    }



    public Type GetRepoType(Type type)
    {
        var types = GetRepositoryTypes();
        Type repoType;
        types.TryGetValue(type, out repoType);
        return repoType;
    }

   public object MakeRepository<U>(DbContext dbContext) where U : class
    {
        // Get repository type 
        // If custom type not found, it should be standart type
        // IGenericRepository<U>
        var type = _repositoryFactory.GetRepoType(typeof(U)) ??
         typeof(IGenericRepository<U>);
        var f = _repositoryFactory.GetFactory<U>();
        var repo = f(dbContext);
        return repo;
    }
}
```

But it's not working for some reason. I have some questions:
1. What type of return value should be in MakeRepository?
2. How should I cast var repo = f(dbContext); to repository type?

Or maybe there is another way to do what I need?

Comment: So the type returned by `GetRepoType` should be used to find the repo ?

Comment: Yes, you're write.

Comment: `But it's not working for some reason.` What is the reason? What **specifically** isn't working?

Comment: I don't undertand, how to cast object repo to repository type.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems really complicated for something that should be simple... The below example is just dummy code, feel free to adapt it to your needs.

```
public static class RepositoryFactory
{
    public static IGenericRepository<T> MakeRepository<T>(DbContext context) 
        where T : class
    {
        var type = typeof(T);

        if (type == typeof(Car))
        {
            return CarRepositoryFactory.CreateCarRpository(context);
        }
        else if (type == typeof(Boat))
        {
            return BoatRepositoryFactory.CreateBoatRepository(context);
        }
    }
}
```

How to use it:

```
var myRepo = (CarRepository)RepositoryFactory.MakeRepository(new MyContext());
```

These kind of codes are not meant to be modified frequently (you don't add a repository at each commit, do you? ;)), so do yourself a favor and keep it simple. :)

Edit : if you really want to keep your code, please add a comment to my response and I see want I'll can do. :)

Comment: And what should I do, if I need to return not IGenericReposity<>, but some 
 of it's child? As I white in question,IOrderLineRepository which extends IGenericRepository<OrderLine>?

Comment: It doesn't matter actually. Instead of returning a IGenericRepository, you return an `object` and then you can simply do : `var repo = (IOrderLineRepository)RepositoryFactory.MakeRepo<OrderLine>();`

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand it correctly, you want to be able to get the repository type by the entity type. I modified your implementation a little and I got it to work as I believe it should.

```
public sealed class RepositoryFactory
{
    public static RepositoryFactory Instance = new RepositoryFactory();

    // Here is custom repository types
    private IDictionary<Type, Func<DbContext, object>> GetCustomFactories()
    {
        return new Dictionary<Type, Func<DbContext, object>>
        {
            // { typeof(IOrderLinesRepository), dbContext => new OrderLinesRepository(dbContext) },
        };
    }

    // Custom repository types
    private IDictionary<Type, Type> GetRepositoryTypes()
    {
        return new Dictionary<Type, Type>
        {
            { typeof(OrderLine), typeof(IOrderLinesRepository) }
        };
    }

    private Func<DbContext, object> GetDefaultFactory<T>()
        where T : class
    {
        return dbContext => new GenericRepository<T>(dbContext);
    }
    private Func<DbContext, object> GetFactory(Type factoryType)
    {
        if (factoryType == null) return null;
        Func<DbContext, object> factory;
        var factories = GetCustomFactories();
        factories.TryGetValue(factoryType, out factory);
        return factory;
    }
    public Type GetRepoType(Type type)
    {
        var types = GetRepositoryTypes();
        Type repoType;
        types.TryGetValue(type, out repoType);
        return repoType;
    }
    public IGenericRepository<TEntity> MakeRepositoryByEntity<TEntity>(DbContext dbContext) where TEntity : class
    {
        var type = this.GetRepoType(typeof(TEntity));
        var f = this.GetFactory(type) ?? GetDefaultFactory<TEntity>();

        var repo = f(dbContext);
        return (IGenericRepository<TEntity>)repo;
    }

    public TRepo MakeRepository<TRepo, TEntity>(DbContext dbContext)
        where TRepo : class, IGenericRepository<TEntity>
        where TEntity : class
    {
        var repo = this.MakeRepositoryByEntity<TEntity>(dbContext);
        try
        {
            return (TRepo)repo;
        }
        catch (InvalidCastException)
        {
            throw new Exception($"Registered repository for entity ${typeof(TEntity).FullName} does not implement {typeof(TRepo).FullName}");
        }
    }
```

}

You can invoke it in one of two way:

```
var d = RepositoryFactory.Instance.MakeRepositoryByEntity<OrderLine>(dbContext);
var d2 = RepositoryFactory.Instance.MakeRepository<IOrderLinesRepository, OrderLine>(dbContext);
```